# Calculating the amount of charges for an object that is electrostatically induced

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, induction

Induction is one of the ways to get an object electrostatically charged. While positive charges accumulate on one side, negative charges accumulate on the other side for an object in an electric field. However, is there a way to determine how many coulombs of charge can accumulate on either side when the object is in a specific electric field? Would all the free electrons on the object accumulate on one side and if so how can I calculate the amount of free electrons in an object?

I think stronger the electric field that the object is subjected to, more charges should accumulate on the sides but I have no idea how to calculate the amount of charges.

Comment: It depends on the shape of the object, and I don't know enough about the area to give a full answer. However the basic property that determines the charge separation is the [polarisibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability).

Comment: @JohnRennie Let's say we have a cylinder and a rectangular prism as shapes of the object. Would we simply sum all the polarisibilities of every particle in the object with integration?

Comment: Actually it's really the [electric susceptibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility) rather than the polarisibility (though it arises from polarisibility at a microscopic level). You'd calculate the polarisation density then integrate it over the object.